# why </p__designer:mapid="d1"> this tag used in css files. What Purpose?

Tags: css

why  this tag used in css files. What Purpose?

Answer (score 0):

That's not CSS. It's bad. A Google search for [p__designer mapid](http://www.google.com/search?q=p__designer%3Amapid) seems to indicate that it's [from ASP.NET](http://forums.asp.net/t/1318179.aspx), specifically when copying as rich text rather than as source.